# Creating a button that links to the host root

Tags: html, button, dns, anchor, root

I have a config page (/config) with a couple of inputs, and i want a "back"-arrow at the bottom, that points back to the startpage

I found out that i can wrap the button in an a-tag to create a link (it works on the startpage as

```
<a href="/config" class="link"><button class="control link">CONF</button></a>
```

)

but inside the config page,

```
<a href="/" class="link"><button class="control backlink">BACK</button></a>
```

doesn't work, and I don't know why. 
the statusbar shows the link correctly, but when i click, nothing happens.
if i click on the outermost edge of the element (just 1px outside the button-image), it DOES work, so i guess there's something wrong with wrapping a button into an a. but strangely it does work on the startpage.

can somebody explain please?

Comment: I don't know why it works on the start page, but a button captures clicks itself, so it will probably 'steal' them from the link. To solve this, you may create a form and a submit button, or just style the link as a button. Or better even: just keep it a link. After all, it is not an action but a link to a different page, so there is nothing wrong with it looking like a link. PS. 'Back' suggestions going back to the place you came from, which is not necessarily the start page. 'Start' or 'Home' would be better titles for that link.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try below like

```
<a href="www.yoursite.com" class="link"><button class="control backlink">BACK</button></a>
```

replace / with your page link. May be www.yoursite.com/index.html

Comment: this is exactly what i want it NOT to be. it should be dynamic, because it's gonna be an app running on a customer server of which i don't know the url. sry for not stating that in the OP

Comment: Then the app or whatever you use must send you a URL and you can use it using $_GET. If you do not know any thing about that url then / not gonna work.